# Fetch data from a JSON Object

Tags: php, json

Hello Stackoverflow Community,
I want to fetch a ID from a JSON String...

My JSON Object:

```
{
    "367393769970204674": {
        "user_id": "367393769970204674",
        "suppress": false,
        "session_id": "18ac9ee4bd6f7aa8f79857da235cefae",
        "self_video": false,
        "self_mute": true,
        "self_deaf": true,
        "mute": false,
        "deaf": false,
        "channel_id": "701221519258419254"
    }
}
```

How can I fetch the first ID (**367393769970204674**) from it...
The String (**367393769970204674**) **isn't** the same, every time I open it from a page.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is it in php or javascript?

Comment: it is written in php

Comment: Decode then `key()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code, help you get Id from json

```
$jsonString = '{
    "367393769970204674": {
        "user_id": "367393769970204674",
        "suppress": false,
        "session_id": "18ac9ee4bd6f7aa8f79857da235cefae",
        "self_video": false,
        "self_mute": true,
        "self_deaf": true,
        "mute": false,
        "deaf": false,
        "channel_id": "701221519258419254"
    }
}';

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$id = key($array);
```

Comment: Why not just `key($array);`?